# Is it possible to have jQuery.click trigger on the top element only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a site where the user can click on any element to edit it's CSS. I use the following to add the click function to all `<li>`, `<div>` and `<ul>`.

```
$('li,div,ul').click(function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

The problem is if I click on a `<li>` element, then I get the alert for that and any element underneath it. (all the containers).

Is it possible to have only the top element trigger when clicked?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to stop event propagation, you do this in jQuery by calling the [stopPropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29) method on the event object.

```
$('li,div,ul').click(function (e) {  
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(this.id); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'd want to use stopPropagation(); inside the click function.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're looking for [.stopPropagation()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29).  Calling stopPropagation will prevent the event from "bubbling" up to parent containers.