# jQuery * selector execute many times

Tags: jquery

Hi i am using jquery * selector and on click event but it executes so many times.
  Look at the following snippet

```
$('*').on('click',function(e){
   alert('hi');
});
```

If i click on element it absolute path is //html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/ul
  /li/a/img i will hi alert 12 times.

Supoose i clicked on another element its absolute path is //html/body/div/div[2] i will 
  get hi alert 4 times how can i reduce this iteration and in e.target i want the details 
  of  the clicked element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is because of event propagation

Comment: You ahould change the `$('*')` to something more specific, so it targets only that item that you need to have action with.  Ideally a `div` or `class` (or both)

Comment: _"in e.target i want the details of the clicked element"_ Can you elaborate on that? I see no code that shows you've tried to do this.

Comment: The asterix selects **all** elements in the DOM, and when clicking an element you're basically also clicking all it's parents, so the click would fire once for each element higher up in the DOM then the element clicked. What does this mean, **you're using the wrong selector** !!

Comment: @adeneo How else would you propose adding a function to every individual node in the DOM which executes only once when that node is clicked?  How do you know this is not a requirement of the user's application?

Answer (score 1):

See similar StackOverflow question: [Is it possible to have jQuery.click trigger on the top element only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584738/is-it-possible-to-have-jquery-click-trigger-on-the-top-element-only)

Add `e.stopPropagation()` to your function to only trigger on the top-most element.  That is, if you click on a `span` which sits on top of a `p` which sits on top of a `div`, only the `span` element will execute the given function.

You can reference the clicked object using `this`.

```
$('*').on('click',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: Hi sorry for late response, i want the last child element not the top most element information, can u plz update it.

Comment: By "top-most" I mean the element closest to the viewer.  You could have 40 divs overlapping one another from different parent nodes and only the element with the highest z-index will receive the click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.stopPropagation` to prevent propagation of the event:

```
$('*').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('hi');
});
```